# Error on creating dynamic form in Angular 17

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, angular17

I want to create a dynamic form that is an array of payments, the user can add a new payment, delete from the array, and edit.

My HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="createLoanPaymentsForm" (ngSubmit)="createLoan()">
    <ng-container formArrayName="createLoanPaymentsForm">
        @for (
            createLoanPaymentForm of createLoanPaymentsForm.controls; // here is the error
            track $index
        ) {
            <div [formGroup]="createLoanPaymentForm">
                <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                    <input matInput formControlName="title" placeholder="Lesson title" />
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        }
        <button mat-mini-fab (click)="addPayment()">Add</button>
    </ng-container>
</form>
```

The configuration of my component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-create-loan-dialog',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
        MatInputModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatDialogTitle,
        MatDialogContent,
        MatDialogActions,
        MatDialogClose,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatStepperModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS,
            useValue: { showError: true },
        },
    ],
    templateUrl: './create-loan-dialog.component.html',
})
```

My `FormGroup`:

```
createLoanPaymentsForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    payments: this.formBuilder.array([]),
});
```

There is an error in my loop, it says:

> Type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>; }' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

The solution for this bug, possible the correct configuration for a `FormArray` loop in Angular 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Reactive Form (HTML) structure is incorrect:

1. `formArrayName` with "payments": `formArrayName="payments"`.
2. In the `@for` loop, you need to iterate the `payments.controls`.
3. Under the `@for` loop, generate each `FormGroup` instance with `[formGroupName]="index"`.

```
<form [formGroup]="createLoanPaymentsForm" (ngSubmit)="createLoan()">
  <ng-container formArrayName="payments">
    @for (payment of payments.controls; track payment; let index = $index) {
      <div [formGroupName]="index">

       ...

      </div>
    }
    <button mat-mini-fab (click)="addPayment()">Add</button>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

```
get payments() {
  return this.createLoanPaymentsForm.controls['payments'] as FormArray;
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jo8fid?file=src%2Fmain.ts)